`git stash pop` confusion after `git stash -k` and changing the branch
I had a situation I don't really understand with git 2.26.2:
Implementing a new feature in a feature branch (say n-feature), I discovered two minor issues that should be fixed in the main branch (say master) as the new feature would take some time to be completed.
So I did this:

git add --interactive and "patch" the files with the new feature's changes, leaving out the parts that should go into the main branch.
"Stash the rest" using git stash -k.
git commit, committing the changes to n-feature.
Checkout the main branch (git checkout master) and do git stash pop.

Doing a git diff I also saw the changes already committed to n-feature (and thus should not go to the main branch with the desired commit), so I recovered using these steps:

git stash again on the main branch (as the stash had been "dropped" again when "popping" it)
Checkout n-feature again
git stash pop to apply the stashed changes found at the main branch

At that point, a git diff showed the right amount of changes, so I continued using:

git stash to save the changes on n-feature again (I thought initial step #2 would have done the same thing)
git checkout master again
git stash pop to apply the new stash
git diff - now the set of changes looked correct, so I continued:
git add -u and git commit
git checkout n-feature

(I might rebase n-feature on master, but the fixes are not essential for n-feature)
So I wonder:

Why wasn't the set of changes correct of the first attempt?
Is there an easier (shorter) way to do the same thing I eventually did (when discovering that some bug has to be fixed on the main branch)?


To the 2nd question, take a look at git worktree. It's a good alternative when git stash makes the situation complicated.

Performing git stash -k adds all the unstaged changes to the stash, and leaves the staged changes intact.

This option is only valid for push and save commands. All changes already added to the index are left intact.

In your case, since you've split the modifications on one or more files into different hunks, your file(s) appear to be both staged and unstaged. Therefore, if you perform git stash -k -- <my_files>, you're stashing the entirety of changes on those files, regardless if you've previously staged them as hunks or not.
If you want to stage some changes and stash the remaining hunks, you need to use the patch option and enter git stash push -p (the -k option is not necessary, as -p implies -k). This version of the command will prompt an interactive menu, like for patch addition (git add -p), which will ask you what you would like to do: split the hunk of changes, stash it, not stash it, and so on.

This option is only valid for push and save commands. Interactively select hunks from the diff between HEAD and the working tree to be stashed. The stash entry is constructed such that its index state is the same as the index state of your repository, and its worktree contains only the changes you selected interactively. The selected changes are then rolled back from your worktree.


The --patch option implies --keep-index. You can use --no-keep-index to override this.

In your case, just repeat the hunk splitting process that you've done during the staging, but this time select the hunks that you want to stash.

Example to answer the question in the comments
Let's say we're on the master branch with the file MyInterface.java:
public interface MyInterface {

    void myCoolMethod();
}

Now, we create a new branch dev and switch to it. While on dev, we add a couple of new methods.
public interface MyInterface {

    void myOtherCoolMethod1();
    void myCoolMethod();
    void myOtherCoolMethod2();
}

At this point, a git diff will show us that the lines with myOtherCoolMethod1 and myOtherCoolMethod2 have been added. But, we only want to commit on dev the line with myOtherCoolMethod1, while on master the line with myOtherCoolMethod2. So, we need to split the hunk of changes with a git add -p -- MyMethod.java, and stage only the first one.
git add -p -- MyInterface.java

# Here, Git shows us the changes on the file, 
# so that we can decide how to split them in patches.

diff --git a/MyInterface.java b/MyInterface.java
index 1f42664..0c212de 100644
--- a/MyInterface.java
+++ b/MyInterface.java
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 public interface MyInterface {

+       void myOtherCoolMethod1();
        void myCoolMethod();
+       void myOtherCoolMethod2();
 }
\ No newline at end of file


# checking the possible options by entering ?

(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,s,e,?]? ?
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 public interface MyInterface {

+       void myOtherCoolMethod1();
        void myCoolMethod();
+       void myOtherCoolMethod2();
 }
\ No newline at end of file


# splitting the change on the file in two hunks

(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,s,e,?]? s
Split into 2 hunks.


# staging the first hunk

@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 public interface MyInterface {

+       void myOtherCoolMethod1();
        void myCoolMethod();
(1/2) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,j,J,g,/,e,?]? y


# skipping the second hunk

@@ -3,2 +4,3 @@
        void myCoolMethod();
+       void myOtherCoolMethod2();
 }
\ No newline at end of file
(2/2) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,K,g,/,e,?]? n

As you can see, entering the s option in the interactive menu allows us to split the current hunk of changes. Of course, in more complex cases, the s can be entered multiple times to further split the current change into the number of patches we need.
At this point, if we perform a git status, we can see that the file looks both staged and unstaged. This is because the file has only been partially staged.
git status
On branch dev
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   MyInterface.java

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   MyInterface.java

Now, to simulate your case, we need to stash the remaining changes, but this time we won't perform a git stash -k, but a git stash -p which will prompt the exact interactive menu of git add -p.
# stashing hunks of changes
git stash push -p

diff --git a/MyInterface.java b/MyInterface.java
index 1f42664..0c212de 100644
--- a/MyInterface.java
+++ b/MyInterface.java
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 public interface MyInterface {

+       void myOtherCoolMethod1();
        void myCoolMethod();
+       void myOtherCoolMethod2();
 }
\ No newline at end of file


# splitting again the change into two hunks

(1/1) Stash this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,s,e,?]? s
Split into 2 hunks.


# skipping the first hunk since we've staged it

@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 public interface MyInterface {

+       void myOtherCoolMethod1();
        void myCoolMethod();
(1/2) Stash this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,j,J,g,/,e,?]? n


# stashing the second hunk that we didn't stage

@@ -3,2 +4,3 @@
        void myCoolMethod();
+       void myOtherCoolMethod2();
 }
\ No newline at end of file
(2/2) Stash this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,K,g,/,e,?]? y

At this point, we can record a commit on dev with just the myOtherCoolMethod1 change, checkout master, and pop on the master branch. After that, if we perform a git diff, we will see that only the change myOtherCoolMethod2 has been brought to the master branch, unlike how it was happening to you where the entirety of changes was stashed.
# recording the partial change on dev
git commit -m "add myOtherCoolMethod1"

# switching to the master branch
git checkout master

# popping the partial change with myOtherCoolMethod2 on master
git stash pop

# making sure that only the partial stash was applied
git diff
diff --git a/MyInterface.java b/MyInterface.java
index 1f42664..d3169e9 100644
--- a/MyInterface.java
+++ b/MyInterface.java
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 public interface MyInterface {

        void myCoolMethod();
+       void myOtherCoolMethod2();
 }
\ No newline at end of file


Sounds interesting (haven't considered the path option before as I didn't know it), but your answer's a bit abstract (for me): Could you provide a simplistic example "work through"?

@U.Windl sure thing! I've updated my answer with an example

Thanks, it's more obvious now. What I usually do is add a %  in front of commands the user has to enter in the shell (% is the ancient C-shell prompt). So it's a bit more clear what's input and what's output. Likewise I use at least two #, so that some  user does not try to enter the comments as command for the root user. ;-)

Just fixed s/path/patch/ in your answer.

@U.Windl oh yeah, didn't notice the typo. Cheers!

Starting with Git, I found the stash extremely useful, because it allowed you to suspend some work, do some other work and finally resume the original work. Lately, I've stopped this use, though I still make use of it for rebasing.
As an alternative, I just commit the unfinished work, turning it into a real commit. Firstly, that is visible, so you can't forget it when you have many branches. Secondly, if you rebase a feature branch, you also rebase those unfinished changes, as you should. There isn't a different workflow involved as it is for stashed changes.
As a prerequisite for this workflow, I would say you should know how to amend, merge and split commits. Further, you need to know the difference between git reset @~1 and git reset --hard @~1.

The reason that you saw the "incorrect" changes after the first git stash pop attempt is that git stash -k puts all uncommitted changes into the stash, even the staged changes. The only difference between a stash with and without -k is that the former does not erase the changes in the index (after all, -k is short for --keep-index).
Since all uncommitted changes were in the stash, the first git stash pop also applies the changes that you had already in the index.
A faster way would have been if you had just committed the staged changes before the first git stash. That is, swap steps 2 and 3 in your first recipe.
The second fastest way would have been if you would have committed the changes that you wanted to transfer on n-feature as a second commit. Then you could have transferred the changes to master via cherry-picking the commit instead of using the stash. (But you would have to undo the commit on n-feature with git reset.)

About you workflow:

when you have git added the changes you want, you can git commit right away, no need to git stash -k.
you could have done your steps 1. - 6. (the second batch) after that.

you could have created a commit with the two small fixes on top of your n-feature branch, and then choose a way to cherry-pick that commit on master


for example:
# add the changes to fix the 2 small issues:
git add -p
git commit -m "fix 2 issues"

# use 'git stash' to put your changes away, on top of n-feature:
git stash

# apply the commit on master
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <that commit>

# return to n-feature and restore your work:
git checkout n-feature
git stash pop

# possibly: rebase your branch on top of master
git rebase master

note that: if <that commit> is the topmost commit of your n-feature branch, you can simply run git cherry-pick n-feature to apply it.

A word about the behavior of git stash :
running git stash actually creates 2 commits:

commit 1 which contains the index (the files that are currently added)
commit 2 which contains the modified-but-not-added files

commit 2 is actually created as a merge commit, between your active commit and commit 1.
You can view this by running gitk stash, or git log --graph --oneline stash, or using any GUI frontend which allows you to view the history of a commit :
$ git log --graph --oneline stash
*  [commit 2] (refs/stash) WIP on my/branch: eacf32b feat: added blablah
|\  
| * [commit 1] index on my/branch: eacf32b feat: added blablah
|/  
* eacf32b (HEAD -> my/branch) feat: added blablah
* eacf32a fixup: blablah
...

running git stash pop or git stash apply will always try to apply both the changes in the index and the changes in commit 2.
In git current version (to this day: 2.44.0) there is no option to git stash to say "just apply the diff between commit 1 and commit 2".

The reason for git stash -kbefore committing is to test whether the partial commit will work as a separate commit (compilation errors, runtime errors, etc.)

I'm "not so firm" with cherry-picking: Does your procedure actually duplicate the commit on both branches, and if so, will a later merge handle the duplicated commit in a smart way?

Another question: If I'd use another (cloned) workspace for master after the commit on n-feature, could I cherry-pick there, avoiding the stash? (As I understand things, I could push the changes on master back to the original workspace while that has a different branch checked out).

yes, running git cherry-pick will duplicate said commit. However, if you rebase your branch after that, git rebase will spot that the changes are the same and will "drop" this commit from your branch. If you keep the two commits and merge, the files should look the same and not trigger conflicts. The only issue would be if the fixes appeared on chunk of codes that are also modified by your feature, but even if there are conflicts they can be resolved.
